# Function returns Uncaught Reference onclick function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When i Click the approve button it say uncaught reference error (ids value) is not defined.I don't think it goes to the function since the console.log() doesn't work.

```
  <script  type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
   var rootRef =
   firebase.database().ref().child("Users").orderByChild('status')
  .equalTo('Tmp');
     rootRef.on("child_added",snap => {
     var email= snap.child("email").val();
     var address= snap.child("address").val();
     var contact= snap.child("contact").val();
     var ids=snap.key;

    var dataSet = [snap.child("fullname").val(), snap.child("email").val(),         
    snap.child("address").val(), snap.child("contact").val(), "<button
    class='btn btn-success' onclick='approve("+ids+")'>Approve</button>"];
     table.rows.add([dataSet]).draw();
     console.log(ids);   
      });     
    } );

      function approve(para){
      console.log("hi");   
      console.log(para); 
      }   

    </script>
```

Comment: Your linebreaks on and after the `snap.child` line's string will cause a `SyntaxError`

Comment: You are not showing what the value of `ids` is, but doing `onclick='approve("+ids+")'` is most certainly wrong. Also unclear why you are doing this in the first place since `approve` directly reads `ids` from global scope and completely ignores the argument it gets passed.

Comment: ids=snap.key, how do you add a parameter in this case?

Comment: You should add event listeners using `addEventListener` (best to avoid inline handlers, they're bad practice and can be difficult to manage, as you're seeing here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever value is inside `ids` variable is being pass to `approve` as a variable name (reference), not as literal value.

Not sure of what your intention is, but I guess what you want to do is this:

`onclick='approve(\'"+ids+"\')'`